# possible XSLT optimization

Tags: xml, performance, xslt

Right now I have XSLT that transforms XML the way I want. But it is working very slow. The main problem is here:

```
<xsl:key name="document" match="/coverage/module/method/seqpnt/@document" use="." />
<xsl:key name="classes" match="/coverage/module/method/@class" use="." />
<xsl:template match="/coverage[@profilerVersion='1.5.8 Beta']">

<xsl:variable name="allDocuments" select="module/method/seqpnt/@document[generate-id()
                                   = generate-id(key('document',.)[1])]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$allDocuments">
                        <xsl:if test="$docUrl = .">

                            <xsl:variable name="docId" select="position()" />


                    ......
                        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Basicly `allDocuments` variable contains list of all documents  - list of strings. I want later to replace attribute in input XML that contains value of that document to document ID - absolute position at this list. Right now i am looping through each record and check if string is equal to the string in list, and if so - get position. Is there any way to achieve better performance? For example to use key on variable?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:
Add a template which generate an unique consecutive id based based on `xsl:number` and `key()`.

```
<xsl:template match="seqpnt" mode="genId">
    <xsl:number count="/coverage/module/method/seqpnt[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kDocument',@document)[1])]"
        level="any" />
</xsl:template>
```

Have a key for the parent node for the document attribute:

```
<xsl:key name="kDocument" match="/coverage/module/method/seqpnt" use="@document" />
```

Than you template can be look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/coverage[@profilerVersion='1.5.8 Beta']">
    <!-- docUrl -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kDocument',$docUrl)[1]" mode="genId" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```